# How can I make a Container like the one in the flutter photo? I'm out of ideas

Tags: flutter

[image: I make a Container like]

> I want to make a Container like the one in the flutter photo, but I
> really don't have any ideas for the triangle with the name, year ...

Answer (score 0):

Use the decoration of BoxDecoration with shape and radius as required.